# Как сделать неактивными кнопки True и False при условии?

Tags: java, android, android-button

У меня есть приложение с `TextView` (в котором поочередно появляются вопросы из массива данных) и 3 кнопки `True`, `False` и `Next` (они отвечают за ответ на вопросы и кнопка `Next` за показ следующего вопроса).
Мне нужно что бы кнопки `True` и `False` были не активны после ответа на вопрос, а после того как я нажал кнопку `Next` они снова стали активные для ответа на следующий вопрос.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
private static final String KEY_INDEX = "index";
private Button mTrueButton;
private Button mFalseButton;
private Button mNextButton;
private TextView mQuestionTextView;

private Question[] mQuestionBank = new Question[]{
        new Question(R.string.question_australia, true),
        new Question(R.string.question_oceans, true),
        new Question(R.string.question_mideast, false),
        new Question(R.string.question_africa, false),
        new Question(R.string.question_americas, true),
        new Question(R.string.question_asia, true),  

@Override
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    Log.d(TAG, "onStart() called");
}

@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    Log.d(TAG, "onResume() called");
}

@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    Log.d(TAG, "onPause() called");
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    Log.i(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState");
    savedInstanceState.putInt(KEY_INDEX, mCurrentIndex);
}

@Override
public void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
    Log.d(TAG, "onStop() called");
}

@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy() called");
}

private int mCurrentIndex = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate(Bundle) called");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState != null){
        mCurrentIndex = savedInstanceState.getInt(KEY_INDEX, 0);
    }

    mQuestionTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question_text_view);
    int question = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].getTextResId();
    mQuestionTextView.setText(question);

    mTrueButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.true_button);
    mTrueButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            checkAnswer(true);
        }
    });

    mFalseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.false_button);
    mFalseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            checkAnswer(false);
        }
    });

    mNextButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next_button);
    mNextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex + 1) % mQuestionBank.length;                
            updateQuestion();
        }

        private void updateQuestion(){
            int question = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].getTextResId();
            mQuestionTextView.setText(question);
        }
    });
}

private void checkAnswer(boolean userPressedTrue) {
    boolean answerIsTrue = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].isAnswerTrue();

    int messageResId = 0;
    if (userPressedTrue == answerIsTrue) {
        messageResId = R.string.correct_toast;
    } else {
        messageResId = R.string.incorrect_toast;
    }
    Toast.makeText(this, messageResId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

После "ответа на вопрос" присваивайте им `.setEnabled(false)`, а после нажатия на NEXT - `.setEnabled(true)`:

```
private void checkAnswer(boolean userPressedTrue) {
    mFalseButton.setEnabled(false);
    mTrueButton.setEnabled(false);
    ...
}
```

**next**:

```
private void updateQuestion(){
    mFalseButton.setEnabled(true);
    mTrueButton.setEnabled(true);
    ...
}
```

Вообще, посмотрите, в интернете полно примеров, как "правильно" писать викторины (похоже это у вас она).